# $A^{-1}x \pmod{26}$ and coprime requirement in Hill cipher

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I am reading Hill cipher from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher) page and I have been stuck on this thought for a while.

Why is there a requirement for $\det(A)$ and $26$ to be coprime in Hill cipher ?

Anybody familiar with Hill cipher and modular arithmetic help me understand this please ?

Comment: $A^{-1}$ does not exist if you cannot divide by $\det(A)$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_{26}$. Such a division is possible, iff $\gcd(26,\det(A))=1$.

Comment: Oh thank you :) I am not familiar with group theory, but it seems you're saying something like $\det(A)x \equiv 1 \pmod{26}$ has no solution when $\gcd(\det(A),26)\ne 1$ ? @JyrkiLahtonen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that for $A$ to be invertible over the integers mod 26, $det(A)$ must be a unit in that ring, i.e. coprime to 26.  Note that because $det(A)det(A^{-1}) = det(I) = 1$, the $det(A)$ must be invertible (as a "scalar").